How to find the position of sub wave file with noise in the original wav file in python?
The length of original wav file is 20 min.
The length of sub wav file is 20-40 seconds.
Finding the position within 1 minute.
I tried to use scipy.io.wavfile to read the file as numpy array and use brute force to find the position with minimum difference. It took a lot of time and did not output the correct position. 
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
import tqdm
_, sub = wavfile.read('video_6_1_filtered.wav')
_, origin = wavfile.read('video6.wav')
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(0, len(origin)-len(sub)):
    temp = np.sum(np.absolute(np.subtract(origin[i:i+len(sub)],sub)))
    if temp < minv:
        minv = temp
        index = i
print(i,minv)


Can you provide an example wav file which reproduces this problem?

@NickODell   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lF2-iiSYw26s_bynPEnMpSUocoan5pi_?usp=sharing

There a few issues here.
First, there is a logic error. When you search for matches, you store the best match position. However, when you print out the result...
print(i,minv)

...you're printing out the loop variable i, which is the last position you tried, not the best. This should be print(index, minv)
I didn't check if this worked - the progress bar told me that it would take 36 hours to test.
In terms of performance, there is a faster way to compare these. Specifically, you can use scipy.signal.correlate() to correlate the two signals, which essentially tries multiplying the two signals at every possible offset. You then look for a peak in this correlation, like this.

The time complexity of doing this convolution is O(N log N) for large signals. In comparison, subtracting the two signals at every offset has a time complexity of O(N^2).
I used the following code to find a match:
# from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tqdm
sub_sr, sub = scipy.io.wavfile.read('video_6_1_filtered.wav')
origin_sr, origin = scipy.io.wavfile.read('video6.wav')
assert sub_sr == origin_sr, "Sample rates differ - must be resampled to consistent sample rate"
correlation = scipy.signal.correlate(origin.astype('float32'), sub.astype('float32'), mode='valid')
index = np.argmax(correlation)
plt.plot(origin[index:index+len(sub), 0])
plt.show()
plt.plot(sub[:, 0])
plt.show()
scipy.io.wavfile.write('video6_subset.wav', origin_sr, origin[index:index+len(sub)])

This finds the closest match, and plots it and the reference signal.
Notes:

For the provided signal, which is a 15 minute long 44 kHz stereo wav file, it takes 11 seconds on my computer to do this correlation. You could speed this up further by either converting the signal to mono, or downsampling to a lower sample rate.

The sample rate of the two signals must match. If they do not, then correlating the two signals will not find the place where they match. The function scipy.signal.resample is useful for this.

I converted both signals to float32 - otherwise it seems to cap the value of the convolution to the maximum value of an int16.

Experimentally, this approach works on the example you provided.
However, keep in mind that this compares the signals in the time domain, and not the frequency domain. Signals can be very different in the time domain while being very similar in the frequency domain, especially if the audio has been processed in a few different ways. When comparing sounds, humans mostly hear them in the frequency domain.



Thank you. I wanted to use correlate. But I am not familiar with it. This helps me a lot.
